# Spring EL does not work

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to write Hello pages with `Spring MVC`.

Hello.jsp

```
<%@page isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>${hello.test()}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Controller-class:

```
package Controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class Hello {

    @RequestMapping(value="/test.htm")
    public String test()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

But when I request `http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/test.htm` method `test()` does not invoked. What is a problem?

Comment: Is there any exception or it just show nothing or the body content without the value you are expecting?

Comment: @JorgeCampos There is no any excpetion. I have empty page, but expected that _hello_ will be.

Comment: Please add to your Hello.jsp this line right after your EL : `<h1>${hello.test()}</h1> <b>I'm in the right place!</b>` and test your page to see what happens.

Comment: @JorgeCampos It's ok! I'm in the right place! displayed.

Comment: Thats odd... Try to change your requestMapping to `value="/test.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET` if it won't work then try this ` @RequestMapping(value="/test")` and call your application just with: `......WebApplication1/test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call controllers methods from the view. You can do it with JSF but not with JSP. Look at this example:

```
@Controller
public class Hello {

    @RequestMapping(value="/test.htm")
    public String test(Model uiModel){
        uiModel.addAttribute("yourkey", "Hello World"); // put some data
        return "Hello"; // means "open Hello.jsp"
    }
}
```

now you can read the data:

```
<%@page isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>${yourkey}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```